# Im getting the previous pass_key value instead of the present one

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

1. Clicking forgot password for the first time will not display pass_key in the email view but stored in pass_key field
2. clicking forgot password for the second time and so on will get the value of pass_key from previous pass_key insertion

UsersController.php

```
<?php
public function forgotPassword()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $query = $this->Users->findByEmail($this->request->data['email']);
            $user = $query->first();
            if (is_null($user)) {
                $this->Flash->error('Email address does not exist. Please try again');
            } else {
                $passkey =Text::uuid(); // create key 
                $timeout = time() + DAY;
                $url = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset'], true) . '/' . $passkey; // Im just generate this link in the view and pass
                $status = $this->Users->updateAll(array('Users.pass_key' => $passkey,'timeout' => $timeout), array('Users.id' => $user->id));
             if($status){

                    $this->getMailer('User')->send('forgotPasswordEmail', [$user]);             
                   $this->Flash->success(__('We already sent a link to your email'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error('Error saving reset passkey/timeout');
                }
              }
        }
    }
?>
```

UserMailer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Mailer;
use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;
class UserMailer extends Mailer
{

    public function forgotPasswordEmail($user)
    {
        // attach a text file 
        $this->attachments([
            'text for user.txt'=> [
                'file'=> 'files/instruction.txt',
                    'mimetype'=>'plain/text',
                    'contentId'=>'3734hf38'
            ],


        // attach an image file 
            'edit.png'=>[
                'file'=>'files/ourlogo.png',
                    'mimetype'=>'image/png',
                    'contentId'=>'734h3r38'
                ]
        ])
        ->to($user->email)
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->subject(sprintf('Forgot Password link  %s', $user->username))
        ->viewVars([
        'username'=> $user->username,
        'useremail'=>$user->email,
        'passkey' => $user->pass_key,
        'userid' => $user->id
        ])

        // the template file you will use in this emial
        ->template('forgotPasswordEmail') // By default template with same name as method name is used.
        // the layout .ctp file you will use in this email
        ->layout('customLayout');
    }
}
?>
```

Template\Email\html\forgot_password_email.ctp

```
<?php
use Cake\Routing\Router;
?>

<p>Your username is:  <?=$username?> </p>

<p>Click on the link below to Reset Your Password.</p>

<?php $resetUrl = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset/' . $passkey]);?>

<p><a href="http://localhost<?php echo $resetUrl; ?>">Click here to Reset Your Password</a></p>

?>




  <?php
        $url = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset'], true) . '/' . $passkey; // Im just generate this link in the view and pass
                        $status = $this->Users->updateAll(array('Users.pass_key' => $passkey,'timeout' => $timeout), array('Users.id' => $user->id));
                     if($status){

        var_dump($url);exit;  I get the exact pass_key but I dont know how to pass the url to forgot_password_email.ctp . I just know how to pass the using this [$user] 


 var_dump($user->pass_key);exit; will retrieve the previous transaction not current pass_key

        .............
    ?>
```

Comment: Are your points 1 and 2 what you want to happen, or what's actually happening? It's not clear. If it's what you want to happen, you should also explain what's happening that's different from that. And if it's what's actually happening, you should explain what you want it to do that it's not.

Comment: I want to email to users the reset link with pass_key but I get the pass_key value from previous transaction when the users click forgot password, the previous pass_key is http://localhost/blog/users/reset/fe4203d1-190d-4e80-8891-6f406f29f9f6       ...

Comment: I also added extra code below @GregSchmidt  but i dont know how to pass the $url variable to the view

Comment: points 1 mean if users request forgot password for the first time the <?php $resetUrl = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset/' . $passkey]);?>    pass_key value did not receive the value,,,,    points 2 if users  requested again the pass_key is print but the value is from previous request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are generating the pass key and saving it to the database, but not updating the `$user` object, so when you pass that to the view it still has the old version.

Try this:

```
$this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
    'pass_key' => Text::uuid(), // create key 
    'timeout' => time() + DAY,
]);
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
```

Here, we update the `$user` entity with the new values, so that they are there for the view, and use the `save` function instead of `updateAll`.

Also, in your view, you should change to the following:

```
$resetUrl = Router::url(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'reset', $passkey]);
```

Comment: it will not save to database, please see this link  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb7f902631913b966716aa947fd3b295

Comment: What error do you get? If it just doesn't save, what does `$user->errors()` look like? Might be a validation issue, which this will point to.

Comment: That doesn't help. Try `pr($user->errors());` when the save fails.

Comment: $this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
    'pass_key' => Text::uuid(), // create key 
    'timeout' => time() + DAY,
    ]);

            pr($user->errors());


               if ($this->Users->save($user)) {

Comment: Array
(
    [username] => Array
        (
            [_required] => This field is required
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [_required] => This field is required
        )

)

Comment: What does your validation look like for the users table? Guessing there's something like `requirePresence('username')` where it should really be `requirePresence('username', 'create')`. Ditto for email, of course.

Comment: i check my validation so i need to add  ->requirePresence('email','create')   and  ->requirePresence('username','create')

Comment: It works now, thank you so much why is it their is a need to add 'create'

Comment: `requirePresence('email')` means that any time you patch the entity, the email field must be present in the data you are providing. By adding `create`, you tell it that the email field must be present when you're creating a new entity, but that it can be skipped when patching. (It can be provided when necessary, just not required.)

Comment: thank you so much.. all the fields in my table I PUT 'create' also